# Iterating through sub-vectors

Tags: c++, iterator, graph-theory

I am trying to iterate through a vector of vectors *neighbors* and simply display its contents.

**The context:** Graph theory. 
*neighbors[i]* is a vector containing all adjacent vertices to vertex i. For this example, the graph is the complete graph $K_5$ of 5 vertices all connected to each other.

**Problem:** I need an iterator to iterate through the sub-vectors, since I (shouldn't) know their length, but I get the wrong answer.

**My attempt**

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_vertices_h; ++i) {
   for(vector<int>::iterator it = neighbors[i].begin(); it != neighbors[i].end(); ++it) {
      cout << neighbors[i][*it] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

**The (wrong) output**

```
2 3 4 -1454373456
0 3 4 -1454373584
0 1 4 0 
0 1 2 -1454373744
0 1 2 3
```

If I just cheat, using the fact that I know each sub-vector has 4 entries, I can avoid the iterator:

**Cheat Solution**

```
for(int i = 0; i < num_vertices_h; ++i) {
   for(int j = 0; j < num_vertices_h -1; ++j) {
      cout << neighbors[i][j] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;
}
```

**Correct output**

```
1 2 3 4 
0 2 3 4 
0 1 3 4 
0 1 2 4 
0 1 2 3
```

Comment: Replace `neighbors[i][*it]` with simply `*it`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `neighbors[i]` is a vector itself, in your first loop attempt, `*it` it is actually the vector element, so you can just `cout << *it` and you'll have the correct result.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks. All I've had is a day's crash-course on STL so I'm still making silly mistakes.